# ffmpeg avcodec_receive_packet return -11

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, android-ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I tried to create a video from a sequence of input images with ffmpeg API.

First I read the AVFrame from input file then pass to `avcodec_send_frame()`, but when I call `avcodec_get_packet()` to get the encoded packet, it returns -11 (output is not available in the current state).

I'm just a beginner so I don't know if anything wrong in my code.

Here is my source code :

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nb_input; ++i) {
        const char *item = input[i];
        ret = open_input_file(item);
        if(ret < 0) {
            goto end;
        }
        packet = av_packet_alloc();
        if(packet == NULL) {
            _log_e("Cannot allocate packet");
            goto end;
        }
        ret = av_read_frame(_ifmt_ctx, packet);
        if(ret < 0) {
            goto end;
        }
        av_packet_rescale_ts(packet,
                             _ifmt_ctx->streams[0]->time_base,
                             _decode_ctx->time_base);

        ret = avcodec_send_packet(_decode_ctx, packet);
        if (ret < 0) {           
            goto end;
        }

        frame = av_frame_alloc();
        if(frame == NULL) {
            ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
            _log_e_2("Failed to allocate frame variable for this file : %s ", item);
            goto end;
        }
        ret = avcodec_receive_frame(_decode_ctx, frame);
        if (ret == 0) {
            /*
             * DO FILTER PROCESSING HERE
             */
        } 

        for (int j = 0; j < 25; ++j) {
            ret = avcodec_send_frame(_encode_ctx, frame);
            if (ret < 0) {
                _log_e_2("Failed to send frame at pts = %d", pts);
                goto end;
            }
            AVPacket *out_packet;
            out_packet = av_packet_alloc();
            if(out_packet == NULL) {
                _log_e_2("Failed to allocate output packet at pts = %d" , pts);
                goto end;
            }
            ret = avcodec_receive_packet(_encode_ctx, out_packet);
            if(ret < 0) {
                _log_e_2("Failed to receive encoded packet at pts = %d" , pts);
                if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN)) {
                    _log_e(" output is not available in the current state - user must try to send input");
                }
                else if (ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
                    _log_e(" the encoder has been fully flushed, and there will be no more output packets");
                }
                else if (ret == AVERROR(EINVAL)) {
                    _log_e(" codec is not opened");
                }
                av_packet_unref(out_packet);
                goto end;
            }
            _log_v_2("Write encoded packet at pts = %d to output file", pts);
            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(_ofmt_ctx, out_packet);
            if (ret < 0) {
                _log_e_2("Failed to write encoded packet at pts = %d to output file", pts);
                goto end;
            }
            av_packet_unref(out_packet);
            pts++;
        }
```

Comment: See [ask]. Your code should be a [mcve] and be in the body of the question. [Edit] the question and tell us what you want to do, show what you tried, and report what result you get.

Comment: @jdv I edited my question, sorry about it.

Comment: BTW, there is no reference to `avcodec_get_packet()` or `avcodec_send_frame()` in your code. Can you show the exact error message or unexpected results you are getting? That being said, "-11" sounds suspiciously like `EAGAIN` which is probably something to do with buffering, as per https://blogs.gentoo.org/lu_zero/2016/03/29/new-avcodec-api/

Comment: oh, sorry, I fixed my source code. 
It's in the 2nd for loop of main() function
and the error message is "output is not available in the current state - user must try to send input" 
I dont know what is it mean?

Comment: Make sure you show the full error message (and is this error at runtime or compile time? Be clear!) in the question itself. Questions should be stand-alone and comments can be deleted. This will help your question get more attention from people who are in a position to give a full answer.

Comment: So, that error message is printed at runtime _from your own code_, and in response to receiving an `EAGAIN`. You need to circle back to the API docs and figure out why you would get this result at this time, and what to do about that. There are a few other resources out there if you search for this API and that return. There is a very good hint in the link I provided, BTW.

Answer (score 4):

The encoder needs several frames of input before it outputs the first encoded frame.  You have to ignore EAGAIN and just feed the next input frame.

Comment: so, how much input frames does encoder need to output the first encoded frame?

Comment: It depends on the number of B frames

Comment: can you explain more about it, I'm just a beginner

Comment: H.264 encodes frames into I B or P frames. I frames use intra encoding only, similar to a jpg image. P frames are "predicted" frames, which are encoded using one or more reference pictures, that is I or other P frames that were encoded before. Finally B frames are "bi predicted" frames, which may use other I, P and B frames. So to encode a B frame, the encoder first has to encode the P frame that follows it. It can only encode that P frame, after you have given it. Often, only two consecutive B frames are used, so to encode the first of these the encoder has to be given 2 more frames.