# ffmpeg video encoder skips first frames

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, hevc

I am new to ffmpeg. I am trying to run this simple video encoding example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
// FFmpeg
extern "C" {
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}
// OpenCV
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: cv2ff <outfile>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    const char* outfile = argv[1];

 // av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_DEBUG);
    int ret;

    const int dst_width = 640;
    const int dst_height = 480;
    const AVRational dst_fps = {30, 1};

    // initialize OpenCV capture as input frame generator
    cv::VideoCapture cvcap(0);
    if (!cvcap.isOpened()) {
        std::cerr << "fail to open cv::VideoCapture";
        return 2;
    }
    cvcap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, dst_width);
    cvcap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, dst_height);
    cvcap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS, dst_fps.num);
    // some device ignore above parameters for capturing image,
    // so we query actual parameters for image rescaler.
    const int cv_width = cvcap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    const int cv_height = cvcap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    const int cv_fps = cvcap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS);

    // open output format context
    AVFormatContext* outctx = nullptr;
    ret = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&outctx, nullptr, nullptr, outfile);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "fail to avformat_alloc_output_context2(" << outfile << "): ret=" << ret;
        return 2;
    }

    // create new video stream
    AVCodec* vcodec = avcodec_find_encoder(outctx->oformat->video_codec);
    AVStream* vstrm = avformat_new_stream(outctx, vcodec);
    if (!vstrm) {
        std::cerr << "fail to avformat_new_stream";
        return 2;
    }

    // open video encoder
    AVCodecContext* cctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(vcodec);
    if (!vstrm) {
        std::cerr << "fail to avcodec_alloc_context3";
        return 2;
    }
    cctx->width = dst_width;
    cctx->height = dst_height;
    cctx->pix_fmt = vcodec->pix_fmts[0];
    cctx->time_base = av_inv_q(dst_fps);
    cctx->framerate = dst_fps;
    if (outctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
        cctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    ret = avcodec_open2(cctx, vcodec, nullptr);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "fail to avcodec_open2: ret=" << ret;
        return 2;
    }
    avcodec_parameters_from_context(vstrm->codecpar, cctx);

    // initialize sample scaler
    SwsContext* swsctx = sws_getContext(
        cv_width, cv_height, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,
        dst_width, dst_height, cctx->pix_fmt,
        SWS_BILINEAR, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!swsctx) {
        std::cerr << "fail to sws_getContext";
        return 2;
    }

    // allocate frame buffer for encoding
    AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
    frame->width = dst_width;
    frame->height = dst_height;
    frame->format = static_cast<int>(cctx->pix_fmt);
    ret = av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 32);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "fail to av_frame_get_buffer: ret=" << ret;
        return 2;
    }

    // allocate packet to retrive encoded frame
    AVPacket* pkt = av_packet_alloc();

    // open output IO context
    ret = avio_open2(&outctx->pb, outfile, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "fail to avio_open2: ret=" << ret;
        return 2;
    }

    std::cout
        << "camera:  " << cv_width << 'x' << cv_height << '@' << cv_fps << "\n"
        << "outfile: " << outfile << "\n"
        << "format:  " << outctx->oformat->name << "\n"
        << "vcodec:  " << vcodec->name << "\n"
        << "size:    " << dst_width << 'x' << dst_height << "\n"
        << "fps:     " << av_q2d(cctx->framerate) << "\n"
        << "pixfmt:  " << av_get_pix_fmt_name(cctx->pix_fmt) << "\n"
        << std::flush;

    // write media container header (if any)
    ret = avformat_write_header(outctx, nullptr);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "fail to avformat_write_header: ret=" << ret;
        return 2;
    }

    cv::Mat image;

    // encoding loop
    int64_t frame_pts = 0;
    unsigned nb_frames = 0;
    bool end_of_stream = false;
    for (;;) {
        if (!end_of_stream) {
            // retrieve source image
            cvcap >> image;
            cv::imshow("press ESC to exit", image);
            if (cv::waitKey(33) == 0x1b) {
                // flush encoder
                avcodec_send_frame(cctx, nullptr);
                end_of_stream = true;
            }
        }
        if (!end_of_stream) {
            // convert cv::Mat(OpenCV) to AVFrame(FFmpeg)
            const int stride[4] = { static_cast<int>(image.step[0]) };
            sws_scale(swsctx, &image.data, stride, 0, image.rows, frame->data, frame->linesize);
            frame->pts = frame_pts++;
            // encode video frame
            ret = avcodec_send_frame(cctx, frame);
            if (ret < 0) {
                std::cerr << "fail to avcodec_send_frame: ret=" << ret << "\n";
                break;
            }
        }
        while ((ret = avcodec_receive_packet(cctx, pkt)) >= 0) {
            // rescale packet timestamp
            pkt->duration = 1;
            av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, cctx->time_base, vstrm->time_base);
            // write encoded packet
            av_write_frame(outctx, pkt);
            av_packet_unref(pkt);
            std::cout << nb_frames << '\r' << std::flush;  // dump progress
            ++nb_frames;
        }
        if (ret == AVERROR_EOF)
            break;
    };
    std::cout << nb_frames << " frames encoded" << std::endl;

    // write trailer and close file
    av_write_trailer(outctx);
    avio_close(outctx->pb);

    av_packet_free(&pkt);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    sws_freeContext(swsctx);
    avcodec_free_context(&cctx);
    avformat_free_context(outctx);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, while using codecs such as **HEVC, H265 or VP9**, the encoder always drops first 27 frames.

More exactly, at line 163:

```
  while ((ret = avcodec_receive_packet(cctx, pkt)) >= 0) {
```

ret is equal to -11 and it doesn't go inside the while loop. From that point onward it's always equal to 0 and no issues are found.

If I use ***MPEG4*** for example, ret is 0 from the start and no frames are dropped.

Comment: http://www.sscce.org/ Please.

Comment: What part of this am I not following ?

Comment: "What part of this am I not following ?" - pretty much *all* of it. If you *did* follow it there would be a simple minimal program in your question, as plain text, that I could copy'n'paste and compile and recreate your problem. That's *not* the case here.

Comment: Is the problem that you cannot click a link and copy/paste ? Should I copy/paste the example myself to the question?

Comment: Don't post links to stuff. Links tend to die over time. Everything relevant to the question should be *in* the question, as *plain text*. If you had taken the StackOverflow tour, this should have been made clear.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you. Now I understood the issue and complied. It wasn't that difficult.

Comment: The code was not in the question when I first saw it. Now it is. Downvote retracted.

Comment: @G.M. I have seen that post. I assume it's something similar but one thing doesn't add up: the frames that are "skipped" (according to that [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51246263/ffmpeg-avcodec-receive-packet-return-11) you shared  never end up in the saved video. I would assume that it waits for a buffer to fill up and then starts writing.